# How to set login expiry time in flutter by shared preferred

Tags: flutter, dart, session, setstate

I want that when login time is greater than 1 hour then session should be cleared and navigate in login page automatically without bloc, provider. I am using setstate according to that please make a whole program for it in flutter

Please make a flutter whole program for managing expiry time of login with setstate